# no "export" main defined in "node_modules\firebase\package.json"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, javascript-import

I want to use firebase Realtime database with express but one line is causing an error: no "export" main defined in "node_modules\firebase\package.json"

config aka firebaseForServer.js file:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const { getDatabase } = require("firebase/database");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");

const firebaseConfig = {};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);
module.export = db;
```

server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("./firebaseForServer");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I tried to remove lines one by one to see which line is causing this error and I found that line `const db = require("./firebaseForServer");` is causing the error. Please tell me what this error means and how I can solve it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We learn that there is no default export in the firebase package entry point (`node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index.d.ts`) from the runtime error message.

```
"export" main defined in "node_modules\firebase\package.json"
```

We can correct this by removing the declared import below:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
```

The declared import is not used anyway in the `firebaseForServer` module.

Also, correct the declared exports in `firebaseForServer`.
In CommonJS module specification, the declared exports must be specified by assigning it to `module.exports` object.

```
const { initializeApp} = require("firebase/app");
const { getDatabase } = require("firebase/database");
const { getFirestore } = require("firebase/firestore/lite");


const firebaseConfig = {};

const db = getDatabase(app);

module.exports = db;
```